# Including custom text in legend of plot

Tags: r, plot

Suppose I have a data that looks like this.

```
> print(dat)
V1    V2
1  1 11613
2  2  6517
3  3  2442
4  4   687
5  5   159
6  6    29

# note that V2 is the frequency and V1 does not always start with 1. 


> plot(dat,main=title,type="h")
   # legend()??
```

Now what I want to do is to plot histogram, and have the mean
and standard deviation included as the legend. In the above example the standard deviation equals 0.87 and the mean eauals 1.66.

How can I achieve that automatically in R?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]This solves the problem with legend creation that Gavin notices.

```
require(Hmisc) 
myMean <- wtd.mean(dat$V1, dat$V2)
mySD <- sqrt(wtd.var(dat$V1, dat$V2))
plot(dat,main="title",type="h")

L= list( bquote(Mean== .(myMean)), bquote(SD== .(mySD) ) ) 
legend('topright', legend=sapply(L, as.expression))
```

This was pulled from [an answer on Rhelp that I posted in 2010](http://markmail.org/search/?q=r-help%20list:org.r-project.r-help%20as.expression%20sapply%20lumley#query:r-help%20list:org.r-project.r-help%20as.expression%20sapply%20lumley%20page:1%20mid:skb3duf5qqrzqd6l%20state:results) that attributed the strategy for the solution to a 2005 exchange between Gabor Grothendieck and Thomas Lumley.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to `sapply(foo, as.expression)`. I think I've used that someone on SO before too now I come to think of it.

Answer (score 2):

This gets pretty close:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = 1:6, V2 = c(11613, 6517, 2442, 687, 159, 29))

addMyLegend <- function(data, where = "topright", digits = 3, ...) {
    MEAN <- round(mean(data), digits = digits)
    SD <- round(sd(data), digits = digits)
    legend(where, legend = list(bquote(Mean == .(MEAN)), 
                                bquote(SD == .(SD))),
           ...)
}

plot(dat, type = "h")
addMyLegend(dat$V1, digits = 2, bty = "n")
```

Which gives

[image: custom legend]

I'm not sure why the plotmath code is not displaying the `==` and a typeset `=`... Will have to look into that.

To see what is going on read `?bquote` which explains that it can be used to replace components of an expression with dynamic data. Anything wrapped in `.( )` will be replaced by the value of the object named in the wrapped part of the expression. Thus `foo == .(bar)` will look for an object named `bar` and insert the value of `bar` into the expression. If `bar` contained `1.3` then the result after applying `bquote(foo == .(bar))` would be similar to `expression(foo == 1.3)`.

The rest of my function `addMyLegend()` should be fairly self explanatory, if not read `?legend`. Note you can pass on any arguments to `legend()` via the `...` in `addMyLegend()`.

Comment: Can anyone explain why plotmath isn't working here? Am I doing something silly?

Comment: Thanks, in my example V2 is the frequency and V1 is the value. V1  does not always start with 1.  Hence the mean should be MEAN=1.66 not 3574.5.

Comment: @neversaint whoops, sorry. Will fix.

Comment: Note sure how you get the mean and sd you do (`mean(1:6)` is not 1.66 etc)

Comment: and for computing SD:  http://www.ltcconline.net/greenl/courses/201/descstat/meanSDGrouped.htm

Comment: Ah, OK - I didn't think this really was a histogram as you really aren't plotting one (the area under the histogram should sum to density 1) and there is a function for that: `hist()` Well I'll leave you to solve those ones yourself. The mean is a weighted mean so see `?weighted.mean` for example